# Main que retorna valores a subprocesos

Tags: c, funciones

Tengo este programa elemental que simplemente hace la suma de 2 números y los escribe por pantalla. ¿Hay alguna forma que el main devuelva el valor de la suma?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void mostrarresultado(float * c);

int main() {
    float a,b,c;

    printf("Ingrese el primer numero:\n");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("Ingrese el segundo numero:\n");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    c = a+b;
    return c;
    return 0;
}

//Este subprocesos simplemente muestra la suma de los números
void mostrarresultado(float *c) {
    printf("El resultado es: %g", c);
}
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. La función `main` ya está devolviendo el resultado de la suma, solo que debería convertirse a `int` ya que la función `main` solo puede devolver números enteros. En CMD el resultado del programa se puede encontrar en la variable `%errorlevel%`

Comment: La idea es que el procedimiento mostrarresultado "capture" el valor de c por referencia y lo escriba en dicho procedimiento

Comment: Tampoco termino de entender muy bien lo que quieres, pero ¿por que no llamas simplemente a la funcion en main? Es decir, `mostrarresultado(&c);`, eso si, debes cambiar `printf("El resultado es: %g", c);` por `printf("El resultado es: %g", *c);`

Comment: Si, eso pensé y funciona, pero no lo quiero hacer así. Si es la única solución válida la tomo.

Comment: Bueno, la función `main` no *retorna* nada a otras funciones. Lo que sí puedes hacer es pasarle por parámetro la información que necesite como dice FJSevilla. Aún así no me queda claro. Por cierto, a menos que necesites modificar la variable original o que el parámetro sea un struct, lo mejor es que la función reciba una copia del valor.

Comment: No me importa igual que el valor de c entre por copia o por referencia al procedimiento mostrarresultado, lo importante es que llegue y entre para poder mostrarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El valor de retorno de la función `main` no está pensado para ser una información para el usuario<sup>1</sup> si no para el sistema operativo. Cuando lanzas un ejecutable el sistema operativo asume un retorno `0` como que el programa ha funcionado correctamente mientras que un valor diferente de cero lo considera un código de error definido por el programa.

Puedes comprobarlo haciendo la siguiente prueba (Windows):

1. Abre la línea de comandos.
2. Ejecuta `dir -Z`.
3. Ejecuta `echo %errorlevel%`.
4. Ejecuta `dir`.
5. Ejecuta `echo %errorlevel%`.

En el paso tres se mostrará un `1`; dado que `dir` no tiene opción `-Z` el ejecutable `dir` finalizó con un error. En el paso 5 se mostrará un `0` porque el ejecutable `dir` finalizó sin errores.

```
C:\Users\PaperBirdMaster>dir -Z
 El volumen de la unidad C es OS
 El número de serie del volumen es: ####-####

 Directorio de C:\Users\PaperBirdMaster

No se encuentra el archivo

C:\Users\PaperBirdMaster>echo %errorlevel%
1

C:\Users\PaperBirdMaster>dir
 El volumen de la unidad C es OS
 El número de serie del volumen es: ####-####

 Directorio de C:\Users\PaperBirdMaster

03/11/2023  10:46    <DIR>          .
19/04/2023  08:40    <DIR>          ..

               X archivos    xxx.xxx.xxx bytes
               Y dirs  yy.yyy.yyy.yyy bytes libres

C:\Users\PaperBirdMaster>echo %errorlevel%
0
```

> ¿Hay alguna forma de que el main retorne valores?

La función `main` siempre va a devolver un valor, y este valor será interpretado por el sistema operativo como el resultado de la ejecución del programa.

Probablemente no te estas refiriendo a que *`main` devuelva valores* si no a que tu programa escriba en la consola de salida. De ser así: ya lo estás haciendo con `printf`. Todo lo que tu programa imprima por consola es el resultado de ejecución y lo puedes desviar a cualquier otro flujo. Por ejemplo, si tu programa fuese así:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mostrarresultado(float *c)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "El resultado es: %.0f", *c);
}

int main()
{
    float a,b,c;

    fprintf(stderr, "Ingrese el primer numero:\n");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    fprintf(stderr, "Ingrese el segundo numero:\n");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    c = a + b;

    mostrarresultado(&c);

    return 0;
}
```

Y lo compilases con el nombre `mateo.exe`. Podrías a continuación ejecutarlo así:

```
C:\Users\Mateo>mateo > resultado.txt
Ingrese el primer numero:
1
Ingrese el segundo numero:
2

C:\Users\Mateo>type resultado.txt
El resultado es: 3
```

La **salida** del programa se redirige al archivo `resultado.txt`. Considerando la salida como todo aquello que vaya a parar a la consola, los mensajes se imprimieron en el flujo de error (`stderr`) así que no van a parar al archivo.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Al menos no directamente.</sub>

Comment: O sea que según lo entiendo, el return del main solo sirve para informar estado y no para devolver o retornar valores.

Comment: Dependerá de lo que entiendas por "*retornar valores*" pero en general, es cierto: el valor de retorno de `main` está pensado para informar al sistema operativo del resultado de la ejecución del programa.

Comment: retornar una variable (de cualquier tipo).

Comment: En ese caso no: `main` no devuelve ninguna variable, devuelve un valor. Ese valor es usado por el sistema operativo para interpretar cómo fue la ejecución del programa.

Comment: ¿Hay alguna forma de que el main retorne valores?

Comment: @AlejandroCaro no se usa para lo que vos quieres el valor de retorno del main, deberias limitarte a simplemente llama a tu funcion mostrarResultado dentro del main y listo.

Comment: @Alejandro el main solo puede retornar números y se espera que sea 0 si no hubo errores.